# Byte order reversed in the Terminal

Tags: python, linux

I am running a C program whose exit status is captured by a Python script using the os.system call on a Linux/little-endian machine.

```
retval=os.system("./cprogexe")
```

If the exit status is 1, the python variable retval is 256 (reverse byte order). Why is this happening if python does indeed follow the local CPU's byte ordering scheme?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The terminology in your question will confuse people. In Linux (and other Unix derivatives), processes do not have "return value". They have standard output, and they have exit status. Your `cprogexe` has an exit status of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the docs for [os.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) (which the docs for [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) refer to for the return value), the return value is:

> a tuple containing its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit
>   number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process,
>   and whose **high byte is the exit status** (if the signal number is zero)

(emphasis mine). Same on Python 2.